# firestore snapshot returns null in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to show the results from cloud firestore in a GroupedListView in Flutter with a FutureBuilder. But the snapshot always returns null. I don't know where is the problem. there is data in cloud firestore but it does not appears in the widget. what is wrong in my code. thanks.

this is the future method:

```
  Future getList() async {
final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
final uid = user.uid;

var myCode = await Firestore.instance.collection('profiles').where('Uid', isEqualTo: uid).getDocuments();

await Firestore.instance
    .collection('profiles')
    .where('Role', isEqualTo: 'chef')
    .where('PartnerCode', isEqualTo: myCode.documents[0].data['code'])
    .getDocuments().then((ds) async {
  if (ds != null) {
      for (var b = 0; b < ds.documents.length; b++) {
        await Firestore.instance.collection('orders').getDocuments().then((orders) async {
          if (orders != null) {
            for (var i = 0; i < orders.documents.length; i++) {
              return await Firestore.instance
                  .collection('orders').document(
                  orders.documents[i].documentID).collection(
                  ds.documents[b].data['Uid'])
                  .where('Stat', isEqualTo: 'delivered')
                  .getDocuments();
```

and this is the FutureBuilder:

```
body: FutureBuilder(
        future: getList(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
            return Center(child: Text('لا توجد بيانات'));
          }
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
          }

          if(snapshot.data == null) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
      
            return Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                  title: Center(
                      child: Container(
                        color: Color(0xff20b198),
                        child: Text(
                          "  مجموع المستحقات : $all ",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                        ),
                      )
                  ),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                ),

                body: GroupedListView<dynamic, String>(
                  elements: snapshot.data.documents,
                  groupBy: (element) => element['Date'],
            groupSeparatorBuilder: (String groupByValue) => Text(groupByValue),
            itemBuilder: (c, element) {
              return Card(
                elevation: 8.0,
                margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 6.0),
                child: Container(
                  child: ListTile(
                    contentPadding:
                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10.0),
                    title: Text(element['kitchenSales'].toDouble() * 0.02.toString()),
                    trailing: Icon(Icons.attach_money)),
```

Comment: It is less likely that you might get a solution for this question, try to produce a minimal version of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `isEqualTo:`  more than once in a single query(see your code below).

You might be getting an error regarding this I am sure.
So that's the reason you are getting a null snapshot.

```
await Firestore.instance
    .collection('profiles')
    .where('Role', isEqualTo: 'chef')
    .where('PartnerCode', isEqualTo: myCode.documents[0].data['code'])
```

**Solution:**
You need to change your queries for getting data.

for more information regarding queries, you can check firebase [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries)